# Как вытащить значения переменных из .load?

Tags: jquery

При загрузке я получаю реальные размеры фоток, чтобы правильно их изменить с учетом пропорций, мне надо потом эти пропорции сохранить, они мне дальше пригодятся, но значения массивов за пределами .load undefined. Как получить эти значения?

```
var $img = $('.slide img');
var wid = new Array();
var hei = new Array();
var k = 0;

$img.load(function () {
    $(this).removeAttr("width").removeAttr("height").css({
        width: "",
        height: ""
    });
    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();
    var kof = width / height;
    if (height >= 600) {
        var width = kof * 600;
        $(this).attr('height', '600');
        $(this).attr('width', width);
        wid[k] = width;
        hei[k] = height;
        k += 1;
    } else {
        $(this).attr('height', height);
        $(this).attr('width', width);
        wid[k] = width;
        hei[k] = height;
        k += 1;
    }

    $('#slides').height(600);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте объявление этих массивов выше load через var